# Let $\alpha$ be a prime in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$, then there is some prime number $b \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $\alpha\mid b$ in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, prime-numbers

How to prove this theorem? All the tools I have are basically the definitions and that in $UFD$ primes and irreducibles are the same. I guess all I am able to prove is that if $\alpha = a + 0i$ then $a$ is the desired prime in $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Do you know that unique factorization works in $\mathbb Z[i]$?

Comment: (The usual English acronym is UFD, FWIW, for Unique Factorization Domain.)

Comment: Yes, also I will accept that answer when possible, I knew it should be simple, thanks.

UFD - yes, sorry, my notes are in spanish (even though I don't speak spanish).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:**

> $\alpha\mid \alpha\overline{\alpha}=N(\alpha)\in\mathbb Z$. Factor $N(\alpha)$ into primes in $\mathbb Z$.